# save reference to morphia if I know it's _id only?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I'm coping and storing some data from a sql database.  I store the data for object A in one pass, and I store object B in a different pass.  Object B has A's _id saved in it.  I would like to save A with a reference to B so that when I load A I get all the information in B at the same time.

However, object A will not be in my memory at the time I'm generating object B, not without huge refactoring.  Since a reference object is little more then an _id anyways is there a way I can tell morphia that they should use A's _id to reference A without first loading all of A into memory to save the object into B?  Would creating an otherwise 'empty' object with nothing but A's _id and every other value set to default and saving it effectively do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working at the level morphia is, you're going to need an A object reference in hand.  That said, it doesn't have to be the full A.  e.g.:

```
B b = new B();
// some work here
b.setA(new A(idForA)));
datastore.save(b);
```

All morphia needs is the collection (which it gets from the mapping information for A) and the _id value for that A.  What will happen here is when `b` is saved, it will create Key (to keep it simple) for that `A` and then create the `DBRef` in the database using that value.  Morphia doesn't care about any other state in an `@Reference` member.  So as long as it can pull out that ID to save, you should be all set.